# Android SQLite Error when downloading file from server

Tags: android, android-sqlite

So I currently store backup files for my sqlite database on my webserver, the problem I am having is when I try to download and import them into my current phone I get this error.

```
 database corruption at line 63697 of [c255889bd9]
 2019-11-07 18:01:20.615 26965-26965/com.my.testapp E/SQLiteLog: (11)      Invalid First byte:0 of page:4
 2019-11-07 18:01:20.615 26965-26965/com.my.testapp E/SQLiteLog: (11) Page      (4) content:
 2019-11-07 18:01:20.615 26965-26965/com.my.testapp E/SQLiteLog: (11)  - 00      01 0F D1 00 0F D1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 2019-11-07 18:01:20.615 26965-26965/com.my.testapp E/SQLiteLog: (11)  - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 2019-11-07 18:01:20.615 26965-26965/com.my.testapp E/SQLiteLog: (11)  - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 2019-11-07 18:01:20.615 26965-26965/com.my.testapp E/SQLiteLog: (11)  - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2D 01 08 00 15 0F 0F 17 33 1B 33 2E 30 30 38 32 31 33
 2019-11-07 18:01:20.615 26965-26965/com.my.testapp E/SQLiteLog: (11)  - 2E 39 35 32 30 31 39 2D 31 30 2D 32 37 20 31 35 3A 31 31 3A 34 39 32 34 37 31 35 39 34 00 00 00
 2019-11-07 18:01:20.615 26965-26965/com.my.testapp E/SQLiteLog: (11) database corruption at line 63741 of [c255889bd9]
 2019-11-07 18:01:20.615 26965-26965/com.my.testapp E/SQLiteLog: (11) statement aborts at 3: [SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY idx DESC] database disk image is malformed
 2019-11-07 18:01:20.615 26965-26965/com.my.testapp      E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler: !@ Corruption reported by sqlite (11) on      database: /data/user/0/com.my.testapp/databases/MY_DB
 2019-11-07 18:01:20.616 26965-26965/com.my.testapp E/SQLiteLog: (11)      Invalid type:0 for page:4
```

But if I download it to my computer and then manually move it into the folder, it imports just fine. Is there something else I should be doing when I download it? Here is the code I use to download it using AsyncTask:

```
File BACKUP_FILE = new File (contextRef.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/backup/" + DB_NAME);

        if (BACKUP_FILE.exists()) {
            if (BACKUP_FILE.delete()){
                Log.e("IFS", "Deleting previous backup: " + BACKUP_FILE);
            }
        }

        int count;
        byte data[] = new byte[4096];

        URL sUrl = new URL(URL_FOR_DOWNLOAD);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) sUrl.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        input = connection.getInputStream();
        output = new FileOutputStream(BACKUP_FILE);

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1)
        {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                input.close();
                return null;
            }

            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("IFS", "Error 127: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the database is used in WAL mode (the defualt for Android 9+) then if the existing database which is being overwritten hasn't been checkpointed the the -wal file still existing may result in such a message.

I'd suggest, when restoring from the backup to delete the -shm and -wal files. However, that does require that the backup was taken when the database being backed up was fully checkpointed.

The other issue could be that you are trying to restore the database whithout fully closing the one being replaced and then re-opening after the restore.

Comment: Wouldn't that all be the exact same regardless of how I got the file? As I mentioned if I manually move the backup file (same one I download) to the folder, everything imports correctly. It is only when the file is downloaded from the server that I get the issue.

Comment: @Jayce [How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html)